# How do I target and end a jquery event before another starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a webpage that has a slowish and dramatic initial load where the header appears in 3 parts. I also have tabs that when clicked transition away the content on the current "page" and transition in the new "page" content. So if a tab is clicked before the initial header transition is finished they overlap and things get messy. I've tried using stop() and finish() but I'm not sure where to put them. What I think I'm trying to do is specify that when a tab is clicked that initial animation is finished instantly before starting the others. However I'm not even sure how to target that animation.

Initial header animation:

```js
$.fn.topSlide1 = function() {
  setTimeout ( function()
              {
    $('.part1').delay(1000).animate({ opacity: '1'  }, 'slow');
    setTimeout (function() {
      $('.part2').delay(1000).animate({  opacity: '1'}, 'slow');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.part3').delay(1000).animate({  opacity: '1'  }, 'slow');
      }, 1100);
    }, 1100);

  }, 1100);


  return this;

}
```

My animation for a clicked tab if that initial page is the one still being displayed:

```js
if (current == '#mag1')

{
  /*Stop animation code here??*/

  /*Starts the fading away transition*/
  $('.part1').animate({ opacity:'0'}, 'slow');
  $('.part2').animate({ opacity:'0'}, 'slow');
  $('.part3').animate({ opacity:'0'}, 'slow');
  $('.bio').fadeDown();

  /*Slides up new page*/
  $(id).fadeUp();
  current = id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call a function at the end - like this

```
$('.part1').animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 'slow', function() {
    //todo if animation finished
    alert('end');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a click handler, you should be able to call `.stop` before you start your next animation. Stop accepts a parameter to jump to the end of the animation, so I would try this:

```
if (current == '#mag1')

{
  /*                           clearQueue, jumpToEnd*/
  $('.part1, .part2, .part3').stop(true, true);

  /*Starts the fading away transition*/
  $('.part1').animate({ opacity:'0'}, 'slow');
  $('.part2').animate({ opacity:'0'}, 'slow');
  $('.part3').animate({ opacity:'0'}, 'slow');
  $('.bio').fadeDown();

  /*Slides up new page*/
  $(id).fadeUp();
  current = id;

}
```

jQuery.stop: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

JsFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rf1y60xz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Fade in slow
    $('.move').animate({opacity: 1}, 5000);
  $('button').on('click', function() {
      $('.move').stop(true, true);
    // Fade out, do other things
    $('.move').animate({opacity: 0});
  })
});
```

Slightly more contrived example, that waits for the opacity animation to finish, and moves another box afterward.

https://jsfiddle.net/rf1y60xz/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Fade in slow
    $('.move').animate({opacity: 1}, 5000);
  $('button').on('click', function() {
      $('.move').stop(true, true);
    // Fade out, do other things
    $('.move').animate({opacity: 0}, function () {
        $('.move2')
        .css('opacity', 1)
        .animate({left: 400});
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: The simple stop() method alone doesn't do it, although I didn't realize I could include multiple selectors in a JQuery call so thanks for that tid bit.

What seems to happen is that on click, it does indeed stop the current animation whether it's part 1 2 or 3. But it doesn't end the propagation/queue of those animations. So if it's on part 2, part 2 will end but part 3 will start regardless, by which time the code has proceeded to the fade out transition already.